# how to sort records with limit clause

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, limit

I have to select top 5 records and display them in ascending order by entry date.

Below is my query:

```
select id,name,entry_date from users order by entry_date desc limit 0,5
```

it gives me latest entered 5 users. but I want them in increasing order by entry date.

How to get them in ascending order with same query ?

Comment: You could nest this in an outer query which does the sort

Comment: Why not just loop from the last to the first in your PHP code! It keeps your SQL and your PHP code simple -> less confusion -> less bugs! (Thanks @mark-b)

Comment: @barsju : I know  can do with PHP code. But am looking for a way how it can be done with mysql

Comment: Got it. It's just that sometimes people get so into the SQL thing that they tend to forget that somethings are better handled in code. It sounded like this was one of those cases, but I'm sure you have your reasons. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work as desired

```
  SELECT  * FROM 
    ( 
        select id,name,entry_date from users order by entry_date desc limit 0,5
    ) as a ORDER BY a.entry_date asc
```